# Is there an editor (or a solution for kate) doing syntax highlighting in a mixed code?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, kate

I'm using [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/) as the editor of my Node.js projects. In the Node.js projects, I sometimes prefer to code whole index.html in a single file. At that time, I need to use:

- html
- css (`<style>...</style>`)
- livescript (`<script type="text/ls">...</script>`)
- javascript  (`<script [type="text/javascript"]>...</script>`)

at the same time. Kate can highlight these codes if they are in their separate files.

How can I make the code highlighted correctly when they are mixed in a single file (preferably in Kate, or any other editor that would run on Linux)?

Comment: Intellij IDEA can do this.

Comment: As far as I could try out, it doesn't even support for nodejs projects. Even if so, we may create an html file but it doesn't highlight these fields separately.

Comment: You're missing a couple of plugins, probably.

Comment: And there seems to be support for node.js too: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/nodejs.html

Answer (score 0):

Kate can do this, too. It is supported in e.g. HTML/PHP highlighting and similar. Just have a look into the respective highlighting xml files to get an idea how to implement a highlighting for this. More information about how to write syntax highlighting files can be found in the [KatePart Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/katepart/highlight.html).